# Is it bad security to use the same private keys and/or keyfiles across production, testnet, and dev?

Tags: go-ethereum, dapp-development, testnets, private-key, keystore

I'd like to understand the security implications of re-using keys across a privatenet, the public testnet, and the production network. If this is bad, why so? Are there advantages or disadvantages to doing such a thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not recommended to use production keys on non-production networks.  Some basic reasons are it's similar to why you shouldn't reuse passwords, or that you wouldn't put $1 in the same wallet as you would put $1000.  There is always a tradeoff between security and convenience: whatever is easy to get to is usually less secure.  Conversely, if your production key is in a safe, every time you want to test something you don't want to have to go to the safe and get it.

It's also good to be aware of [replay attacks](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26/what-is-a-replay-attack), even though replay attacks between [Ropsten and production network are prevented if using an updated client](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10211/what-replay-attack-protections-does-ropsten-provide).