# Geth failed to load genesis block

Tags: go-ethereum, genesis

When i try to load genesis block using the following command: 
`geth --datadir privchain init genesis.json`, i get the following error,

> Fatal: **failed to write genesis bloc**k: invalid character '.' after object key:value pair

Here is my genesis file:

```
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 15,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0
  },
  "difficulty": "200000000",
  "gasLimit": "2100000",
  "alloc": {
    "af8bd873406715dc1444077bb9d65c8800f7acdf": {
      "balance": "400000"
    }
  }
}
```

I am using this genesis file from this link: 
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Private-network
can someone help me out here please? Thank you

Comment: Probably you should add `0x` as a prefix to your address given in `alloc`

Comment: no, it didnt help . Thank you though

Comment: Are you trying to run a private network? There are some alternatives.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to run a private ethereum network . can you tell me some alternatives?

Comment: follow this : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13547/how-to-set-up-a-private-network-and-connect-peers-in-geth/13548

Comment: I've tried with the latest version of geth 1.6.5 and it works with your genesis.json (I've a difficulty of '2000').

Comment: Works for me as well -- geth 1.7.2-stable. Could it be you are using an outdated geth?

Comment: You might miss double quote.. in my case.
check it first.