# What does the extraData field of a block represent?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, private-blockchain, storage

I am trying to save some data into a block.
The extraData field has a constant value since block 1.
Also where does the data parameter of sendTransaction() function get stored?

Answer (score 3):

**Please find reference in this answer here:**
[What does each genesis.json parameter mean?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2376/what-does-each-genesis-json-parameter-mean)

**Excerpt here:**
"extraData An optional free, but max. 32-byte long space to conserve smart things for ethernity."

Comment: Or, to paraphrase, you can put anything you want in the `extraData` field.

Comment: Some mining pools use it for [logging](https://etherscan.io/block/6371882) their blocks.