# Can someone verify this answer: gasLimit vs. minGasLimit

Tags: gas-limit, genesis

I would have thought that these are the upper and lower bounds of how much gas can be used in any one transaction.  But the mainnet file has the same value for each of these.  Can someone explain what these values actually mean?

(Hint: please don't provide the same link to the same thread that fails to explain these.  I mean this one: [What does each genesis.json parameter mean?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2376/what-does-each-genesis-json-parameter-mean))

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research and trial and error (which should not have been necessary if there was a good glossary... ahem) I think I discovered that in the Parity chain spec file, these refer to:

**gasLimit**: This is the maximum amount of gas that your chain spec allows to be spent in the genesis block itself.

**minGasLimit**: This is the minimum amount of gas that may be required for processing any block in the blockchain.

Please correct this if I am wrong.